# Getting a specific Jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, jt400

I'm using this [repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jt400/jt400/9.5/) to get the driver for my database.

And using this gradle config: `compile('net.sf.jt400:jt400:9.5')`

I know I can add the specific jar file locally. but is there any way to get gradle to add the `jt400-9.5-jt400_jdk8.jar` instead of default `jt400-9.5.jar`?

Comment: I think it would have to be published with own pom.

Comment: @Antoniossss actually I've just discovered there is something that is called classifier which can be appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use maven classifiers, they are defined after the version, so it'd look like:

`compile('net.sf.jt400:jt400:9.5:jt400_jdk8')`